# Data from default_popup not getting passed to content_scripts through background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am creating a Firefox addon(like chrome extension). I am able to pass the user selected value in the default_popup to background script, but not able to pass from there to content script.

My manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Beautiful Website",
  "description": "Customize website color based on User selection",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["notifications"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background_script.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/logo_64.png",
    "default_title": "Beautiful Website",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "content_scripts":[
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["cs.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

My index.html

```
...
<body>
            <form id="colorForm">
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" id="red" name="usercolor" value="red" checked />
                        <label for="red">Red</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" id="green" name="usercolor" value="green" />

                        <label for="green">Green</label>
                    </div>
...
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>

        </body>
<script src="index_scr.js"></script>

</html>
```

It gives Firefox popup like

[image]

Then the index_scr.js

```
var form = document.querySelector("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    var data = new FormData(form);
    var output = "";
    for (const entry of data) {
      output = entry[1];
    };

    browser.runtime.sendMessage({
      userColor: `${output}`
    })

    event.preventDefault();
  }, false);
```

My background_script.js .

```
function handleFormSelection(data){
  browser.notifications.create({
      "type": "basic",
      "title": "Updated Color Page",
      "message": data.userColor.toUpperCase()
  })

}

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleFormSelection);

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(sendData)

function sendData(tab){
    browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {data:'dummyData'})
}
```

The Content script(cs.js) is

```
function letsDoThis(data){
    console.log('Inside CS ', data);
}

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(letsDoThis)
```

Problem is not able to get a method to send/way to send color received from user to Content script.

Can someone please help with the last part.

Comment: browserAction.onClicked isn't invoked when you have default_popup so use browser.tabs.sendMessage directly right in your popup script instead of browser.runtime.sendMessage

Comment: Changed the popup script(index_scr.js) as you said @wOxxOm. But it is giving the error **Error: Incorrect argument types for tabs.sendMessage.**


`var form = document.querySelector("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", sendColor, false);

function sendColor(tab) {
  var data = new FormData(form);
  var output = "";
  for (const entry of data) {
    output = entry[1];
  };

  browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {userColor: output})

  event.preventDefault();
}`

Comment: Well, debug it.

Comment: @wOxxOm I debugged it and it is getting the submit of the form.

_tab is_  **submit { target: <form#colorForm>, isTrusted: true, currentTarget: <form#colorForm>, eventPhase: 2, bubbles: true, cancelable: true, defaultPrevented: false, composed: false, timeStamp: 0, cancelBubble: false, originalTarget: <form#colorForm> }**

Comment: Uhm, see the documentation for browser.tabs.sendMessage - the first parameter is an integer tab id, which you can get via browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}), look for examples.

Comment: Yep. I had to use the tabs.query to get it running. So, i have to change my logic completely. Everything working fine, except Content Script is choosing all websites, but i wanted to target only github.
Below is my code in github 
@wOxxOm. Can you please have a look.
(https://github.com/nabendu82/beautifulGithub)

Comment: Thanks for the help @wOxxOm. I was finally able to create my addon. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/amazing-github/